# Unable to start neo4j afer copying elasticsearch jar files to plugin folder

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j

I am getting below error in neo4j console.log after copying jar files from dependency folder of elasticsearch to plugin folder of neo4j

```
2015-12-11 08:08:21.697+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@623dc0b8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attach
ed cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@623dc0b8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.

org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@623dc0b8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exceptio
n.

at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:67)

at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:234)

at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:97)

at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.start(CommunityBootstrapper.java:48)

at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.main(CommunityBootstrapper.java:35)

Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@623dc0b8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:462)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)

at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:194)

... 3 more

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db

at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:143)

at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:43)

at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)

at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer$1.newGraphDatabase(CommunityNeoServer.java:66)

at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:95)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)

... 5 more

Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@28d2afd8' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:434)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:66)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:102)

at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:139)

... 10 more

Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No dependency satisfies type class org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.StringLogger

at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.DependenciesProxy$ProxyHandler.invoke(DependenciesProxy.java:79)

at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.getStringLogger(Unknown Source)

at org.neo4j.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchKernelExtensionFactory.newKernelExtension(ElasticSearchKernelExtensionFactory.java:39)

at org.neo4j.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchKernelExtensionFactory.newKernelExtension(ElasticSearchKernelExtensionFactory.java:20)
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly? Also, it looks like version information of OS, java, Neo4J and elasticsearch will be helpful here.

Comment: Neo4j version - Community version 2.3.1 on ubuntu
ES version - 2.1.0

neo4j.properties

elasticsearch.host_name=http://localhost:9200
elasticsearch.index_spec=product:Product(product_name)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be because Neo4j and ElasticSearch using different version of Lucene.

In JVM you can't have one jar with two different versions.

Comment: How to check the version of Lucene running on Neo4j?